# How do I determine which eclipse sdk is being used?

Tags: linux, eclipse, sdk

I have multiple eclipse SDKs installed on my linux notebook.  They are in different directories and I do not remember which is the last one I installed.  The command 'which eclipse' gets me /usr/bin/eclipse.  /usr/bin/eclipse is a shell script that (among other things) sets ECLIPSE=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.  /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse is a real executable (not a link) that was copied in from elsewhere.

The command 'eclipse' brings up a functioning eclipse.  My question is: If I want to expand the capabilities of this eclipse, which SDK do I need to make changes to - ie which SDK do I insert add-ons?  That is, given an executing eclipse, how do I find the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

On the `Help > About Eclipse` dialog click `Installation Details` for lots of details about the installation. The `Configuration` tab contains the paths of what is being used.

Adding to Eclipse is generally done using `Help > Install New Software` and you don't normally need to know where the Eclipse install is for this!